# Método save() do mongoose não salva

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Quando chamando o método save do mongoose ele parece não estar fazendo nada. 
O código do save é o seguinte:

```
var newProjects = new projectModel({
    "teste":"teste"
});
newProjects.save(function (err){
    if(err){
        console.log("Erro");
        return;
    }else {
        console.log("Funcionou");
        return;
    };
});   
console.log("Passou")
```

O que acontece é que ele nunca loga as mensagens de "Erro" nem a "Funcionou", mas loga a mensagem "Passou", e também não cria a collection no MongoDB. Por ser a primeira vez que o save dessa model é executado, creio que a criação devia ser feita.

A variável ProjectModel é inicializada assim:`var projectModel = mongoose.model('Projects');`

E a modelagem da collection é a seguinte:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var projectsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    teste: {type: String, required: true}
});

mongoose.model('Projects', projectsSchema);
```

Alguma ideia do que pode estar causando o problema?

Comment: Não conheço o mongoose diretamente, mas pelo código que você postou aqui você não está chamando o save propriamente, está definindo a função que será chamada quando a ação de salvar for feita. Está aparecendo o "Passou" pois ela está na mesma sequencia de execução que a definição da tua função save. Dá uma olhada na documentação do mongoose e verifica quando essa função de save é realmente executada.

Comment: Sim, ela está na mesma sequência de execução, mas eu esperava que antes de o "Passou" aparecer, deveria ser impresso o "Erro" ou o "Funcionou".

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o metodo `Model.create()` onde ele cria um registro em seu banco de dados a partir de sua model:

```
try {
   const projectModel = await projectModel.create({teste:"teste"});
   return projectModel ;
}
catch(err) {
    return err
}
```